# TypeError: send_photo() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю простейший бот для телеграма, который раз в три секунды отправляет рандомную фотографию из папки в канал телеграма.

Код:

```
import telebot
import os
import random
import time

TOKEN = ''
tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN) #create a new Telegram Bot object
chat_id = '@12121201'


while True:
    photo = open(random.choice(os.listdir("D:\ph")), 'rb')
    tb.send_photo(chat_id, photo)
    time.sleep(3)
```

(Токен вырезан)

И получил эту ошибку при отправке фотографии:

```
    tb.send_photo(chat_id, photo)
TypeError: send_photo() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

В другом треде пишут, что эта функция еще не реализована в `telebot`, но у многих людей она работает, как это можно исправить?

Comment: попробуте код из вон того ответа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200541/sending-photo-from-url-with-telegram-bot

Comment: Теперь выводит ошибки: `File "C:\Users\Maks\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 15, in listener
    chat_id = m.chat.id
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'chat'`

Comment: Может у вас древний питон и древняя версия бота?

Comment: и pyTelegramBotAPI и telebot последних версий, по крайней мере таких, как на Pypi

Answer (score 1):

pyTelegramBotAPI    3.8.2

```
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

print(bot.get_me())


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def test(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('files/test.JPG', 'rb'))
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```